Compliance table is not being updated in Oracle EBS
In purchasing the compliance details table, some columns pull a description associated with a particular DFF.
The examples are:
Business Size in compliance table  - Attribute2 in PO headers
Nature of Goods and Services in compliance table- Attribute10  PO headers
Unfortunately, there are POs for which the values have been entered at the PO level, while no description is present in those columns in the Compliance Detail table.
I have checked that for the same attribute value in the po_headers there are values in the compliance for some po's and some are empty.
and the DFF is mandatory to be filled at the PO level so it is being filled while the po is being created. but some of the po's are not populating the respective values in the compliance table.
where is the connection breaking?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
